# Click Once Installer - Publishes to site but not sure how to access file

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I have just learned about Click Once in Visual Studio and I wanted to create an application for my website that people can download.

The application is built and I have even published it to my FTP/website.
However, I have looked at other sources on here, YouTube and Google and have not been able to find help as to how exactly I can get the file to install when someone goes to the webpage. Or, how do I reference the file in a link on my webpage so that when they click the file will start the install process?

Thanks ahead of time for any and all help.

-Colt

Comment: Just put a link to your .application file somewhere.

Comment: @Evk what would that look like? When i publish it on my FTP- how would I link to that VIA a HTML link or image link on my website? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Installation Folder URL by going back into the project properties in Visual Studio, going to the publish tab and then taking whatever url is in the Installation Folder URL.

For example if your installation URL was https://mywebsite/myapp/ then you would want to go to https://mywebsite/myapp/setup.exe.

Comment: mysetup folder is:

http://www.overworldinnovations.com/MyApp/

and yet when i put the setup.exe at the end it does not work :/